# Ubuntu 18.04 alt+shift+tab does not switch apps backwards

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

Title says it all.

Since upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04 <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine i.e. switches apps cycling forward. But <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not switch apps backwards.

I went to **Settings > Shortcuts** and noticed that the shortcut for *Switch applications* is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I tried <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and they worked as expected, but i'm hardwired to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+[<kbd>Shift</kbd>]+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. So I switched this shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Still <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only switches forward, and not backwards.

Changing the shortcut to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> again works as expected for both forward and backward switching.

Any idea how to make the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> work for backward app switching?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Ubuntu 18.04 is blocked by another shortcut. It may have been set by Gnome Tweaks (among other possibilities), you can query the current value via:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

The default is `[]`, but if it returns a value that includes `grp:alt_shift_toggle`, then this explains the behavior that you are seeing.

You can run this command to free the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

[source1](https://blog.popstas.ru/blog/2018/05/01/alt-shift-tab-in-ubuntu/) [source2](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048836/500443)

Comment: I was starting to give up! Thanks. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: It resets `Alt` + `Shift` toggle input source behavior

Comment: @Piterden that happened to me too. Did you find a workaround where the two can coexist? For me each one precludes the other.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. It's fokken GnomeShell. Honestly, I loved Unity. Why did they get rid of it?

Comment: One solution is to abandon `Alt`+`Tab` for switching applications, and use `Super`+`Tab` instead.  Makes more sense.  Then, you can have both `Alt`+`Shift` for switching keyboard layouts and `Super`+`Shift`+`Tab` for switching applications backwards.

Comment: My problem was that I'd set `Alt+Shift` to switch langauge, which in results, disabled setting alt and shift in a shortcut together. I switched to `Win+Space` and the problem was fixed. Hope it helps some guys

Comment: Annoying. This worked perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04, yet is broken in 19.10. No reason for it. The context is not a textbox - it should not assume I want to change input language..

Answer (score 11):

I was able to resolve it using [Gnome Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) GUI.

Open Tweaks and go to Keyboard & Mouse, then click - Additional Layout Options:
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWPK3.png), ans then uncheck Alt+Shift under Switching to another layout section
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os57c.png)

That fixed it for me.

Comment: god bless you man, it worked!

Comment: This worked! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE and the answer from dima.rus helped me diagnose the problem: it was caused by a conflict with the shortcut for keyboard language switching.

What solved the problem for me:

1. Change the `Main shortcuts` in `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Layouts -> Shortcuts for Switching Layout` which was <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. **EDIT**: Do not set it to the otherwise rarely used <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as once I mapped and started using it, in some rare cases it caused the keyboard caps lock *mode* getting enabled and stuck (as indicated by the keyboard's caps lock light indicator), and forced me to reboot. EDIT: or instead of reboot, just start `Onboard` (the KDE on-screen keyboard) and use it to press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> virtually.
2. Set the `Reverse` to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in `System settings -> Task Switcher -> Main -> Visualization -> Shortcuts`
3. Log out and in again to KDE