# How can I disable keyboard layout switching with both shift keys?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

I’m using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS. During a recent automatic software update I was shown a `debconf` dialog, which is something that usually never happens in Ubuntu. The configuration in question was about switching between keyboard layouts. I think I just accepted the default.

Now pressing both <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys switches keyboard layouts in GNOME (and probably generally in X). This is pretty bad, since I’m using the Neo keyboard layout, where pressing both <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys is the way to toggle caps lock.

This new <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> layout switching is apparently separate from the GNOME layout switching. GNOME layout switching still works via <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and shows me the pop-up with the keyboard layouts as usual. The new layout switching, however, doesn’t show any pop-up.

How can I disable this <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> layout switching again? I already tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=high x11-xkb-utils`, but this didn’t offer me any configuration options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were probably hit by [bug #1762952](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1762952). One way to fix it:

1. Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and replace the line starting with

   ```
   XKBOPTIONS
   ```

   with

   ```
   XKBOPTIONS=""
   ```
2. Run this command to disable it from the desktop settings as well:

   ```
   gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
   ```