# keyboard shortcut problem

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, copy

upgrading 17.10 to 18.04 I stupidly set a keyboard shortcut for switching input languages to <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>, and it messed up copy paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, now they work with <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>, which is highly inconvenient.

I tried to fix it in keyboard settings, but I can't see either of those 3 positions (neither 'alternative switch to next source' - changes input language, nor copy or paste to clipboard) on the list so can't change it there.

I suppose I would need it to fix it manually, but I don't know what command to type in.

as on the screen below 2nd position says command.

[image]

So do you know how could I change it back? Do I need to add it manually if it's not on the list of shortcuts in settings->keyboard?
If yes what command to use?

Would be very glad for help.

Comment: Even if the question is not exactly the same as yours, I'd guess that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048836) applies to your problem too.

Comment: thanks so much, I found an answer there. I installed gnome tweaks and went to Key and Mouse -> Additional Settings -> Switching to next source -> here I unclicked the box with my setting

Comment: Right, that's the GUI way. Great that you solved the issue!

Answer (score 3):

1. Install gnome tweaks "sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks".
2. Open gnome-tweaks.
3. Go to "Keyboard and Mouse" and then click on "Additional Layout Options [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPtV9.png)
4. Click on "Switching to another layout" and deselect "Left Ctrl". [(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFCpy.png)