# Corrupted default keyboard settings on specified user

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

After a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, my left <kbd>ALT</kbd> doesn't work properly. It can be used for switching windows with <kbd>L-ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, but any normal hotkeys like <kbd>L-ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or PyCharm bindings that start from <kbd>L-ALT</kbd> don't work (but when that ALT bind is somewhere in the middle - everything's all right).

Also, in the **System Settings > Keybindings** menu, I can't change any default shortcuts: when I click on a shortcut, nothing happens, but I still can add my own. The window for changing shortcuts works normally and *reset all* kind of works, too, but give no desirable changes.

I created a new user and on that account, everything works well.

I tried to play with `setxkbmap` and stuff like

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

to set everything to default, but still <kbd>Left-ALT</kbd> is just causing windows to move out of focus or show their window context menu (after who knows what manipulations in GNOME Tweaks/dconf-editor)

So, I just want a way to set everything to its default value.

But there is definitely some bug at work, if the shortcuts configuration menu doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable keyboard layout switching with both shift keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048831/how-can-i-disable-keyboard-layout-switching-with-both-shift-keys)

Comment: Attention CV reviewers: **Bug as per OP's self-answer!  :-)**

Comment: Asking someone for help pushing yourself for finding answer more intensively sometimes) But here it was pure luck

Answer (score 3):

Luckily I found solution - bug caused by [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) gnome extension

Removed, rebooted and all works fine now.

Comment: Also reported to the author