# Ubuntu 20.04 - How to disable a shortcut for switching keyborad layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have two keyboard layouts which I usually change using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (which is fine).
The problem is that <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> causes the same effect. This later key binding causes some troubles when typing capitalized words, because it switches layout even if there is a (small) latency between pressing the different Shift keys.

I didn't find any place where this key binding is configured.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @user68186. I know this settings location but I couldn't find there the Shift+Shift keybinding (I'm OK with Super+Space and Alt+Shift but not with Shift+Shift)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable keyboard layout switching with both shift keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048831/how-can-i-disable-keyboard-layout-switching-with-both-shift-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the same as in:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1048836/1237677

(I upgraded my system from Ubuntu 18.04)

The solution suggested in the link above solved the problem to me.