# Reset keyboard shortcut for changing language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts

I upgraded to 21.04, then a message appear to set shortcut for changing languages (RO - EN). For some reason I set Left Shift + Left Ctrl.

Now I realized I can't open a new tab in terminal anymore (with Ctrl + Shift + T) because the language is changing instead.

I opened the Region & Language settings, then Input Sources: Keyboard Shortcuts. Here the message is: These keyboard shortcuts can be changed in the keyboard settings.

Ok, I opened the Keyboard Shortcuts and I have Typing: Switch to next input source: Super + Space.

But I can't see the Ctrl + Shift shortcut I want to remove. So, where can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable keyboard layout switching with both shift keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048831/how-can-i-disable-keyboard-layout-switching-with-both-shift-keys)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, no. The same issue after I did the settings.

Comment: Well, then you probably made a mistake. Unchecking it in Tweaks, as you say solved it, is basically the same as running the command at 2. in the accepted answer in the duplicate question. And you need to change `/etc/default/keyboard` also or else it will reappear after reboot. Anyway, good that you figured it out.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No issues after reboot. It's strange. But I'm happy it is solved. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing Tweaks.

In Keyboard and mouse > Additional layout options > switching to another layout - I unchecked the custom Ctrl + Shift setting.

No restart needed.