# Why does not the Gnome Keyboard settings override/clear the xkb settings?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

A recurring issue (at least for users that utilize more than one keyboard layout or input source?!), is that `Alt+Shift` is a sticky setting for changing input source. That means, even if you change Gnome's keyboard settings to something else, like `<Super><Space>` (a popular choice, it seems), `Alt+Shift` still sticks! Which not only *ruins using Alt+Shift+Tab, but also every other shortcut in all programs using Alt+Shift as modifiers*, including IntelliJ (my main work tool). That sucks and is super-confusing.

Today [I learned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041899/ubuntu-18-04-altshifttab-does-not-switch-apps-backwards) that this is caused by a setting that is stored outside of gnome's keybindings schema (`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings` has the `switch-input-source` setting):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']
```

Removing this setting "fixes" things (doing `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`), but why should I ever need to do so? Why can't simply Gnome clear this by default and use its own setting? This is so bad UX and almost seems like a glitch of some kind, but it *seems* as if it has been there for 4 years now, so in that case it should have been fixed. Is there any good reason for that behaviour?

**Related**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45447/other-than-alt-shift-to-switch-keyboard-layout-any-other-xorg-key-combination
- [Ubuntu 18.04 alt+shift+tab does not switch apps backwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041899/ubuntu-18-04-altshifttab-does-not-switch-apps-backwards)

---

Ubuntu 21.10 distro upgraded from 21.04

Comment: What is our current Ubuntu version?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu 21.10 distro upgraded from 21.04

Comment: Better add that info to the question. Actually, you nailed the issue, identified it correctly as a useability issue, so that is something to be taken up by the developpers. Nobody can give a more sensible answer than what you already indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Both the mechanisms you describe have their merits and complete each other, even if they don't always play well together.

However, I thought that [bug #1762952](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1762952) was fixed. Has something happened since then which makes the system define <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> by default again?

Comment: I am not sure about the issue - if this is new or a regression case. I upgraded to 21.10 from 21.04 some weeks back, and ever since this has been an issue.

Comment: Verified this is not a regresssion _on new installs_. I just did a clean install of 21.10 on another computer. The ` org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` option is empty, so this seems to be related to upgrades only.

Comment: @oligofren: Thanks, that's useful info. I'll try to find the reason for it.

Comment: It might be that having two ways of switching have merits (like working for non-Gnome environments), but I still think that the desktop tooling could _indicate_ to the user that another setting has been enabled that will affect input switching if the xkb settings has been enabled. That would avoid a lot of hair pulling :)

Comment: I am not sure where to follow this up on a better channel, but I have found out that the xkb settings reappears after each reboot, meaning I always need to do this: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options;` to clear the `['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']` options that are being set. I am running Ubuntu inside VMWare. Do you think this could affect this somehow? Maybe VMWare Tools interferes?

Comment: @oligofren: In that case you need to drop `grp:alt_shift_toggle` from `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: That would indeed fix it, but would you have any idea how I can figure out which software has set these options? According to this Ubuntu man page the XKBOPTIONS is normally unset: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/keyboard.5.html. I see the last change is Feb 8.

Comment: @oligofren: I suppose it's the `keyboard-configuration` package. See the bug I mentioned in my answer.